# Mapping between virtual and physical address in memory paging

Tags: memory, paging, cpu-architecture

In some system, paging mapped a virtual address (a8b43f​​)<sub>16</sub> to a physical address (13efd43f)<sub>16</sub>.

What can be inferred about the page size?

Comment: Is the answer "nothing" an acceptable answer ?

Comment: @nos I'm afraid it's not an acceptable answer. Please see the updated question.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate, since you can't tell anything about page size from this piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not enough information to determine anything for certain, you can infer an upper limit on the page size by noting that the lower 13 bits of both addresses are the same. As we know the page index is the lower x bits of the address, if we find the maximum page index, we can determine the maximum page size. 0x00A8B43F and 0x13EFD43F share the same lower 13-bits ('b1_0100_0011_1111). Thus, the maximum the page size can be is 2^13 words, or 8 kwords. If the memory is byte addressable, this means a page size of 8KB.

However, without more information, knowing the exact page size is not possible as the shared bits might have come from a convenient mapping.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, pages could be 2^8 words, like I said you can only get a max for the page size. Any where from bit 0 (2^1 word page size; bits 1 through 12 matching is coincidence) to bit 12 (2^13 word page size; no matching bits are coincidence) are valid page indexes, resulting in different page sizes. But, you can only get a maximum page size of 2^13 words as bit 13 does not match. I dont understand what you mean by the other end; the upper bits are the ones replaced by the virtual -> physical mapping, so you need to find the most lower bits matching in order to determine max page size.

Comment: The important part is not that they share the lower 13 bits, but rather that they differ on the 14th - that means, as you said, that the page can't be more than 8K, otherwise bit 14 would have been part of the offset and would have to match.

Comment: @Leeor Yes, I probably should have made it more explicit that I stopped after 13 bits because bit 13 (14th bit) of the two addresses differ; thanks for pointing that out :)